# I am looking to retrieve a list of regions using IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a new project to practice by my self, I am looking to return a list using `GetAll` method, but I'm struggling with it. I'll show the code here so hopefully someone can help.

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 and SQL Server for the data.

```
namespace Northwind.Web.Data.Repositories.Regions
{
    public interface IRegionRespository
    {
        Task<bool> Create(CreateRegionViewModel region);
        Task<bool> Update(RegionViewModel region);
        Task<RegionViewModel> GetById(int id);
        Task<IEnumerable<RegionViewModel>> GetAll();
    }
}

async Task<IEnumerable<RegionViewModel>> IRegionRespository.GetAll()
{
    var regionList = _nordwinContext.Region.ToList();
    return regionList;

    //var query = _nordwinContext.Region.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
}

    
    public class Region
    {
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public string RegionDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to add your code as text and provide any errors you get in order for anyone to help your properly.

However, I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say that the images you uploaded indicates that you're neglecting to return the actual value of your method, or the list. You need to add the return keyword with the value you get from your data context.

```
async Task<IEnumerable<RegionViewModel>> GetAll()
{
   var regionList = _nordwindContext.Region.Tolist();
   return regionList;
}
```

**Edit 1** (received further details of the error)

The method `GetAll()` wants to return a type `RegionViewModel`, but your data context is returning the type `Region`. In order to get around that you should change one of them. Let's try with the Interface and implementation.

```
 async Task<IEnumerable<RegionViewModel>> IRegionRespository.GetAll()
        {
            var list = _nordwinContext.Region
                 .Select(r => new RegionViewModel
                 {
                     RegionDescription = r.RegionDescription,
                     RegionId = r.RegionId
                 }).ToList();

            return list;
            //var regionList = _nordwinContext.Region.ToList();
            //return regionList;

        }
```

Comment: Here the error when I try to return that list as you recommended above.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Northwind.Web.Data.Entities.Region>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Northwind.Web.ViewModels.Region.RegionViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That's  because the data you get from your datacontext isn't of type RegionViewModel but an Enitity called region. 

Do you have a model called region?

Comment: I've edited the post, sorry I am new to this. There you have more details, when I try to return a regionList from the DataContex, I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: No worries - we all have to learn. 
I've edited my answer with something new you can try.

Comment: Seems to be the right logic for it, but how abuot if I still want to user the RegionViewModel type and pass it to the Model itself.

Comment: Then you would need to change the entity type in the datacontext to RegionViewModel instead of Region. 
If my answer worked for you please accept it as the solution so the issue can be closed and help others in the future. I'll still reply to some comments if you need help.

Comment: Would I be able to do a Query, Select or something like that using the RegionViewModel as it shows on the description above, so I can show that information in the frontend?.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment before now. Seems like you figured out how to use the select and return the viewmodel - great :) 
Remember to accept the answer as the solution, and have nice day :)

Comment: Thank you for your support. Have a nice rest of the day.